# Getting an Ajax call to return into my Javascript context

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

Given an instantiated JavaScript object/class can I make an Ajax call from that class and have the returning success function callback into the caller's object?

Currently I can get the callback to return back into the object, but I lose the "this" property, which kills the state of my object

```
function BaseConsoleHelper()
{
this._iconIndex = 0;
} 
BaseConsoleHelper.prototype = {
Dispose: function()
{
this._previousIndex = 0;
},
GetVisitConsoleIcons: function(name)
{
    this._iconIndex = 500;

    SampleNamespace.MyService.GetConsoleIcons(name, this.IconsGenerated);
},
IconsGenerated : function(result)
{ 
    //I should be 500.....but I'm not, cause "this" has become something else
    alert( this._iconIndex );
}
};
```

BTW I using asp.net ajax 3.5 (and, wow, isn't inheritance different in here than pure JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
SampleNamespace.MyService.GetConsoleIcons(name, this.IconsGenerated);
```

to:

```
SampleNamespace.MyService.GetConsoleIcons(name, 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.IconsGenerated)
);
```

See [this article](http://www.dennydotnet.com/post/ASPNET-AJAX-createDelegate-and-the-JavaScript-this.aspx) for more examples of retaining references to `this` within Web Service calls.

Comment: thx, just discovered the same thing.

Followup Question:   Function.createDelegate vs. Type.createDelegate?

Comment: @Alex: They're the same thing (literally). MS AJAX aliased `Function` as `Type`, but officially you're supposed to do `Function.createDelegate` instead of `Type.createDelegate`.